# Subversion multi checkout post-commit hook?

Tags: linux, svn, hosting, web

The title must sound strange but I'm trying to achieve the following:

SVN repo location: /home/flx/svn/flxdev
SVN repo "flxdev" structure:

```
 + Project1
 ++ files
 + Project2
 + Project3
 + Project4
```

I'm trying to set up a post-commit hook that automatically checks out on the other end when I do a commit.

The post-commit doc explicitly lists the following:

```
# POST-COMMIT HOOK
#
# The post-commit hook is invoked after a commit.  Subversion runs
# this hook by invoking a program (script, executable, binary, etc.)
# named 'post-commit' (for which this file is a template) with the
# following ordered arguments:
#
#   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository)
#   [2] REV          (the number of the revision just committed)
```

So I made the following command to test:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
echo "Updated project $REPOS to $REV"
```

However when I edit files in Project1 for example, this outputs **"Updated project /home/flx/svn/flxdev to 1016"**

I'd like this to be: **"Updated project Project1 to 1016"**

Having this variable allows me to specify to do different actions per project post-commit. How can I specify the project parameter?

Thanks!

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `svnlook`.

Quick and dirty would be to try something like:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
CHANGED_DIRS="`/usr/bin/svnlook -r $REV dirs-changed $REPOS`"

echo "Updated paths $CHANGED_DIRS in revision $REV"
```

You may want to try running `svnlook help`; it will list out the various commands you can use/information you can get.